# Variable not visible outside its scope

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

I have a word template, with bookmarks etc. most of this works fine..but im having trouble with a switch statement.. i loses its scope outside of this.

i have it checking the currency type applied to a premium for insurance, if its 'pounds' then it replaces the text 'pounds' with the '£' symbol, same for Euros and Dollars, etc.

the reason im here is to ask for suggestions or acknowledgement that what im thinking is right and possible.

what i think would work was if this was a seperate 'Method/function' if you will.. but lack the knowledge/expertise of where to begin.

i have had a go, but Visual Studio is having none of it.. here is the switch statement:

```
switch (sCurrency.Trim())
{
    case "Pounds":
        sCurType = "L";
        break;
    case "Euros":
        sCurType = "€";
        break;
    case "Dollars":
        sCurType = "$";
        break;
    default:
        sCurType = " ";
        break;
}
```

it then goes on to be used in such a way:

```
t_tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = sCurType + iExcess;
```

the problem is as i said earlier, this variable losses its scope so it either no longer exsists or holds no value.. 
what the best way to go about this..??

Comment: I am not really sure what your problem is, but why don't you simply put your `switch` statement inside a static method and return the value instead of setting a field?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend letting the framework deal with the actual formatting when it comes to currencies. The problem is it's not just as simple as getting the correct symbol you then need to format the actual value itself i.e. symbol placement, decimal separator etc. So rather than working out which *symbol* to use, look at working which *culture* you want to base your formatting on e.g.

```
public CultureInfo GetCultureForCurrency(string currency)
{
    switch (currency)
    {
        case "Pounds":
            return new CultureInfo("en-GB"); // GBP (UK)
        case "Euros":
            return new CultureInfo("fr-FR"); // Euros (France)
        case "Dollars":
            return new CultureInfo("en-US"); // Dollars (USA)
            break;
        default:
            return Thread.CurrentCulture; // Default system culture
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var culture = GetCultureForCurrency("Dollars");
t_tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = iExcess.ToString("C", culture);
```

Comment: +1, I would also mention that it may be worth considering the cost of instantiating a new `CultureInfo` vs the number of times this method will be called. OP seems to be updating a data grid, so some caching might be useful (which is of course outside the scope of this question).

Comment: Rather than passing the currency in as a string, consider using an enum of all of the values your application plans to support.

Comment: @Groo yep caching would probably be a good idea, probably a good shout for being a static helper class. However, that's more of a performance thing so I didn't want to bloat the answer with that sort of stuff.

Comment: @Servy My answer is based off the OP's existing code, they are getting the currency in as a string. Ideally, yes it would be nice if the currency was an enum, but it's not *really* a necessity.

Comment: excellenty thanks for all your helps guys!! much appreciated and a knowing of where to come for future help is a big bonus!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a method like this:

```
private string ToCurrencySymbol(string currency)
{
    string currencySymbol = null;

    switch (currency.Trim().ToLower())
    {
        case "pounds":
            currencySymbol = "£";
            break;
        case "euros":
            currencySymbol = "€";
            break;
        case "dollars":
            currencySymbol = "$";
            break;
        default:
            currencySymbol = " ";
            break;
    }

    return currencySymbol
}
```

Which you then call like this:

```
t_tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = ToCurrencySymbol(sCurrency) + iExcess;
```

But really you should be using the [RegionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tk23w8x.aspx) class, which has a CurrencySymbol property which gives you the currency symbol for a specific region.

Comment: Using `return`s inside the `switch` statement would simplify your code a bit.

Comment: @Groo, "simplify" is subjective. Personally I do not like multiple return statements in a method, but that is not relevant to this question.

Comment: "Simplify" as in "significantly reduce the length of the function and number of keywords".

Comment: But does it make it any easier to understand? Shorter is not necessarily simpler; "return" is a side effect, and multiple side effects can increase complexity.

Comment: Well, as you've said, it's subjective, but ["guard clauses"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) are really sometimes considered a more readable solution. Your method, for instance, has 5 places where the same variable is being assigned to. These are nothing less than "side effects", and mutating the state of a result variable at multiple places means you'll have to check each of them to ensure correctness in all cases. Anyway, for a small method with a single switch like this one, it's irrelevant. Readability is in the eye of the beholder. :)